# Centers buttons and text to the right of the second button but not centered

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a popup window which has a multiline textbox with 2 buttons under that. A Cancel and a Save.

**I have:**

```
<div style="width: 650px;">
    <div style="padding-top: 10px; text-align: center">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtTest" Width="530px" TextMode="MultiLine" Style="word-wrap: break-word; height: 200px; overflow: auto; vertical-align: top" runat="server" AutoComplete="off" />
        <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender2" WatermarkCssClass="textwatermarkNotes" TargetControlID="TxtOther" WatermarkText="Please enter a message here..." runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;">
        <asp:Button ID="BtnCancel" OnClick="btnCancel_click" CssClass="buttonSmall" CausesValidation="false" Text="Cancel" runat="server" OnClientClick="EncodeText()" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="BtnSave" runat="server" CssClass="buttonSmall" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label Width="130px" ID="txtCharMax" Text="" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have in the code-behind to say like "100 character max". But I want the Cancel and Save centered and the "100 character max" to the right of the Save.

On the 4th DIV I thought I could do something like:

```
<div style="float:left">
    <asp:Label Width="130px" ID="txtCharMax" Text="">
</div>
```

But that didn't work.

What is the best/easiest way to do this? Leaving CSS out but using the Style tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
          <button style="margin-left:100px">cancel</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button>save</button>
        <span style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">
            TEXT
        </span>
</div>
```

Making the text inline-block allows it to align alongside the buttons.  Then giving it a width allows us to use margin-left on the left button to shunt it along right by the same amount so that the buttons appear centrally.

Comment: I will give it a try but when I look at the source and the IE 11 F12, it's basically already doing that almost exactly. But again, I will give it a try to rule everything out.

Comment: It turns out that the button style really help center it. :-) Thanks!